# How to access an Ubuntu Host PC running a Windows Guest VM connected to a Remote PC?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, virtual-machine, routing

**Environment:**
Host PC: Ubuntu
Guest VM: Windows
Remote PC: Ubuntu

**Setup:**
Host PC <-> Guest VM <-> VPN <-> Remote PC

**Description:**
For some reason, I can only use my VPN in Windows
I setup the Guest VM with 2 NW interfaces:

1. NAT
2. Host-only adapter (I use this to share my VPN from Guest -> Host PC)

**What I can do:**
I can access the following:
Host PC <-> Guest VM
Remote PC <-> Guest VM
Host PC -> Remote PC (I added a route to the remote PC via Host-only adapter IP)

**Question:**
How can I establish access from Remote PC -> Host PC?
My idea is to also add a route from remote PC -> host PC, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I tried to add this in the remote PC:

- ip route add host PC IP/mask via VPN IP of Guest
- ip route add host PC IP/mask via Remote IP

But I still can't access Remote PC -> Host PC...
Any ideas or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Connect your host PC to the VPN

Comment: @mully, thanks but I mentioned it in the post that I can only use the VPN in Windows OS..